# .htaccess prevents php code

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

**Update:**
Their support team has come back with me saying their membership plugin works externally based on function calls made to it. I have included these two links. If anybody can help me figure this out sooner, I'll trade ya some design work in exchange!

http://codex.wishlistproducts.com/class-reference-wlmapiclass/
http://codex.wishlistproducts.com/function-reference-wlmapi_is_user_a_member/

My php knowledge is beginner at best but from what I'm gathering I need to make a call to this wlmapiclass to access the original internal class, and then use wlmapi_is_user_a_member to return my true or false that I need in order to display the page?

Huge thanks to anyone that can help me out!

**Original Post:**

I need your help. I've done quite a bit of research on .htaccess code and I haven't yet been able to find anything that might answer my question.

Basically, using Wishlist Member for Wordpress, a script is included into the .htaccess for each folder it protects. Unfortunately, the .php files I have inside that folder no longer are able to use their functions (such as ) Here's the current .htaccess code:

```
# BEGIN WishList Member Folder Protection
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^month-1/*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?wlmfolder=month-1&restoffolder=$1 [L]
# END WishList Member Folder Protection
```

The html still works great, everything loads up except for the php include code (code shows up grey when I try to inspect the page, but visible). If I want to make a change to a ton of pages, it's better to have the php include if I can.

**Things I've tried:**

- Uncommenting the condition, setting it to only affect .php files directly (so as not to affect the .inc they include) [RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  .(php)$]
- Putting the inc files in a folder inside the parent folder (
- Deleting the .htaccess file (this fixes it, but unprotects all the files)
- Including "AddType application/x-httpd-php .php"

**Things to note:**

- index.php shows up as plain text when .htaccess has that Wishlist
  Member code, all other php pages load but without the include calls
- month1 folder contains entire folder structure. .inc files are inside that folder.
- Include function works when .htaccess code is deleted.

Let me know if I can provide any more information, and thanks in advance!

Comment: what do you mean by "php include code"

Comment: Perhaps more fitting here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @BlondeyGill, do you have access to the apache logs? If so, please take a look at that.

Comment: @manRo - By "php include code" I am referring to <?php include 'filename.inc'; ?>

Comment: Progrock: You're definitely right, any idea how I can quickly change this thread?

@SZenC I should, currently researching the location of it for my hosting provider. Will update when I do find it

Comment: The problem is likely to be that .htaccess keeps rewriting your URL to a mess, as it is executed multiple times.

Comment: @SZenC I came to the same conclusion, but then it had me wondering why wouldn't it still work with a hardcoded url for an external file that isn't affected by any .htaccess. I've added an update in case you can help! I wasn't able to find my apache logs unfortunately but there seems to be a work around